# Postgresql slow on simple filter

Tags: postgresql

I had a largeish table (5 megarows) with log data which was getting slow so I pruned out old stuff down to 1.5 megarows, vacuumed it and performance went up. Next day, it's slow again! Row count good, table vacuumed. Even a simple count(1) with one where takes 40. No configuration change to the DB etc, graphs show no CPU or I/O abnormalities

explain analyze says

> Parallel Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..728860.27 rows=441932 width=0) (actual time=0.017..41333.374 rows=346046 loops=3)
> Filter: (actor = 'API'::text)
> Rows Removed by Filter: 205478

Any explanations appreciated

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: Can you share the complete query, the ddl for the table and indexes involved and the complete result (in plain text) from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement?

Comment: What *really* I can't understand that I have my table 'foo' with 1.8Mrows and my table foo_archive with 6.8Mrows in the same schema. 

They're identical and I just dump older entries with insert into foo_archive(select * from foo...)

If I do the sample query against foo, it takes the 40 seconds. But if I query the same against the much larger foo_archive, it takes less than 4 secs. So it shouldn't be an I/O issue.

Any way my table foo might have broken in a way that vacuum can't fix just by me archiving rows or something?

Comment: I noticed that I *do* strip out some xml from the archive table but it looks like foo and foo_archive are about the same size on the disc so even if both tables are trudged through, one would expect the performance to be about the same and not off by a factor of 10(?)

Comment: running the same sample query against a "create table as select from" clone gets the response time down from 40s to around 2s after query cache warmup so I think I'll just recreate/rename the table. But it would be interesting to know what could have caused it...